# Remove margin between elements when like breaks

Tags: css, margin

I have margin between buttons like this:

```
.button + .button {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

Buttons are inside `<div class="row">`, which will wrap around with smaller screen size:
[image]

Is it possible to remove margin in second line?

Comment: No directly, no. CSS has no way to select elements based on what “line” they are shown on. You will have to find a different way of applying those margins - for example, switch to a margin-right instead. Or go `flexbox`, and use on the space distribution methods that provides.

Comment: Well, you could try and use `:nth-child() `Selector but you will need to fix the margin and remove it at different breakpoints. But that will only work if you know for sure these items will not increase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below CSS.

```
.button {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    margin-right:0.5rem
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best workaround, just row needs to have margin-left: -0.5rem; so that buttons are still aligned to content above them

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you would like to do is line up the second row all the way to the left. That can be difficult to handle when the screen size changes and you get different buttons on different lines, as you are finding out. But it's easy if you set the display up as a flex — you don't have to worry about margins at all.

Have a look at this:

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 35px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
    <button>Button 6</button>
    <button>Button 7</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Try shrinking your screen and see how the buttons stay lined up. This is what `display: flex` was designed for. All you have to do is have a container (the `div` in this example) that you set to `display: flex`. If you want to have overflow wrap to the next line, you set `flex-wrap` to `wrap` (if you don't set this, the flex display will try to shrink the widths on all of your buttons and stuff them onto one line). And then you can set whatever `gap` value you want it and be done with it.

If you don't want to use a flex, you can set the left and right margins to equal values instead of just setting the left margin: `margin: 0.5rem` will set all four margins to 0.5rem and everything will line up. The problem with this is when you want to have the buttons flush against the sides of their container. If you want that, then flex is the easiest way to go. Otherwise, you have to play with negative margins for containers. They have problems of their own, in particular if your container has a border.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the buttons have a margin to the right (margin-right: 1rem) instead of the left to ensure that the spacing remains intact by making the spacing after rather than before, but it would help remove the spacing on the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what your html looks like, but try target them with a media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width:from screen width with issue in px) and (max-width:to screen width with issue in px) 
for example- 
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px)
{
 .button + .button:nth-child(4){
  margin-left: 0px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

parent is same margin but negative:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
div {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
button {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</section>
```